# Use REST to sum a column?

Tags: list, infopath, sql-server, rest

I want to retrieve items from a SharePoint list using REST, and then sum one of the columns. I'm brand new to REST, and didn't see a way to do this on MSDN. Is it possible to sum a column in a REST query?

I'm using InfoPath to collect the data. Would I be better off submitting it to SQL Server and then building the report from there, instead of submitting the data to a SharePoint list and using REST?

Comment: You shold not run queries directly towards SharePoint databases, always only through supported API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use aggregate functions with REST.

*"This release does not support Aggregate functions (sum, min, max, avg, etc) as they would change the meaning of the ‘/’ operator to allow traversal through sets."
[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc907912.aspx)*

My only suggestion would be to get the items and do calculate the SUM on client side, if possible.